# Second maven repository in gradle on an Android Project

Tags: android, maven, gradle

this is the way I added facebook repository in order to use FacebookSDK on an gradle-based android project

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "http://mente.github.io/facebook-api-android-aar"
    }
}
```

Now I have to add a new repository for the umano sliding menu (https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

I've tried something like this (but it obviously doesn't work):

```
 repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "http://mente.github.io/facebook-api-android-aar", "https://bitbucket.org/luciofm/m2repository/raw/master/"

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add it separately:

```
maven {
   url "http://mente.github.io/facebook-api-android-aar"

}
maven {
   url "https://bitbucket.org/luciofm/m2repository/raw/master/"
}
```